# Input Placeholder goes out even Padding-right is applied

Tags: css, input, placeholder

I'm facing issue with the placeholder as below image.
[image]

It's working fine with text in Input.
[image]

I've applied padding-right with 40px, its working fine for text but not for placeholder.

My Code

```
height: 40px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
color: #000;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
background: url('../images/icon-search.png') no-repeat #f6f5f4;
background-position: 97% 50%;
width: 100%;
padding-right: 40px;
line-height: 18px;
```

Its also working fine with all browser. Facing this issue with Safari (Ipad) only.

Thanks

Comment: What browser(s) are you trying this in? Seems to work ok for me in Chrome.

Comment: Are you using standard HTML placeholder on the element? Or some other kind of label placement?

Comment: Its working fine with all browser, it gives issue with Safari (768x1024) resolution

Comment: Can you make a test case for this on [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Seems to work fine for me in Safari.